# Subida de datos a Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

Estoy intentando subir una serie de datos a Firebase pero por alguna extraña razón no me sube nada de lo que indico, todos los valores que recibo por parámetros son correctos y el elemento esta bien declarado así que no se si sea algo de la función.

```
private crearPost(titulo: string, url: string, nombreArchivo: string) {
    const post: ArchivoSubir = {
      titulo: titulo,
      img: url,
      key: nombreArchivo
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(post));

    // this._afDB.list('/post').push(post);
    this._afDB.object(`/post/${nombreArchivo}`).update(post);
    this.imagenes.push(post);
    this.mostrarToast('Post Creado!');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrige la siguiente linea

```
this._afDB.object('/post/' + nombreArchivo).update(post);
```

"nombreArchivo" es una variable y solamente hay que concatenarla a la ruta en donde quieres guardar los datos, también ten cuidado con el tipo de comillas.